# TypeScript generic type that accepts (1) a tree and (2) a type with which all the tree's nodes should become a union

Tags: typescript, replace, types, tree, union

Lets say I have an arbitrary tree type:

```
type Tree = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: "d"
    }
  }
}
```

And a type with which I'd like to make each tree node a union. For instance, `"f"`. In other words, the tree should become the following:

```
type Tree = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: "d" | "f"
    } | "f"
  } | "f"
} | "f"
```

My goal is to be able to create ^ this type using a utility type––perhaps something along the lines of `DescendantsUnionedWith<T, F>`, where `T` could be the `Tree` type from above and `F` could be `"f"`.

In trying to solve this, I first created a generic `ChildrenUnionedWith` type:

```
export type ChildrenUnionedWith<O extends object, T> = {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K] | T;
};
```

Next, I attempted to create the recursive tree-deep type:

```
export type DescendantsUnionedWith<Tree extends object, T> = Tree extends object
  ? ChildrenUnionedWith<DescendantsUnionedWith<Tree, T>, T>
  : Tree | T;
```

The result of course was a circularity error :/

Does anyone know of a way that I can achieve the `DescendantsUnionedWith` utility type?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.... ignore what it says the type comes out as it doesn't read what it actually is. the tests are below....

Let me know if there's any problems.

```
type DeepUpdate<T, Append> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? DeepUpdate<T[K], Append> | Append : T[K] | Append
}

type Tree = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: "d"
    }
  }
}


type IsEqual<A, B> = [A] extends [B] ? [B] extends [A] ? true : false : false


type test = IsEqual<DeepUpdate<Tree, "F">, {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: "d" | "F"
    } | "F"
  } | "F"
}>; // true.
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution! Thank you! I wonder why though the compiler resolves the type to equal `{
    a: "F" | ChildrenUnionWith<{
        b: {
            c: "d";
        };
    }, "F">;
}` . –– it would be nice if it would continue down the tree. One again, thank you!